# How do I read SNx4HC244 logic diagram?

Tags: datasheet

I want to use `SN54HC244` chips so I started reading the data-sheet.
It can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/product/SN54HC244?dcmp=dsproject&hqs=pf) or directly [here (PDF)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54hc244.pdf).

On the first page I don't understand the logic diagram:
[image: SN54HC244 logic diagram]

`1A1`, `1A2` and `1A3` output labels are all `1Y1`. From the table on the second page and the given the pin numbers (18, 16, 14, 12) I think the labels should be as the following image:
[image: SN54HC244 fixed logic diagram]

Am I mis-understanding something or is the data-sheet wrong?

Comment: The DS is wrong. Not the first time either.

Comment: Question asked on TI forum: https://e2e.ti.com/support/applications/hirel/f/935/t/686168. I'll answer to myself if I get an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I mis-understanding something or is the data-sheet wrong?

Yes, the current version of the datasheet is wrong.

Notice the text "SCLS130**E**" on the header of most pages in the current datasheet, which tells us that it is revision *E*. The mistakes which you highlighted were only introduced in the latest revision to that TI datasheet, when it changed from revision *D* (August 2003) to revision *E* in May 2016.

Here is the equivalent, **correct**, diagram from the previous revision *D* datasheet - see the header text "SCLS130**D**" below:

[image: logic diagram from Texas Instruments 74HC244 revision D datasheet]

Comment: Confirmed by TI: https://e2e.ti.com/support/applications/hirel/f/935/p/686168/2528388#2528388.

They said they will fix this in the next data-sheet version :)

Comment: @VictorLamoine - Thanks for the update, that's good news :) Well done for finding the mistakes. I wonder how many other people were confused by them, in the 2 years since those mistakes was introduced!